# btrfs check shows checksum verify failed even after scrub

Tags: btrfs

Running `btrfs check` shows several errors like this (13 in total):

```
checksum verify failed on 369098752 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
```

All wanted checksums are zeroes, which is obviously suspicious.

After running `btrfs scrub` I had exactly 13 corrected errors in metadata and multiple uncorrectable errors in data blocks (fixed by restoring affected files from backup).

However, running `btrfs check` again shows the same 13 checksum errors.

I have two questions: what are the numbers in the error referring to? All search results mentioning this question result in no answers. My guess is it's a logical address, but `btrfs inspect-internal logical-resolve number /path` gives `ERROR: logical ino ioctl: No such file or directory`, and it's obviously not an inode as well (dmesg actually explicitly refers to these numbers as logical addresses, pointing to the metadata leaves, but it doesn't specify of what kind).

And second question, what can I do about these checksums? All the btrfs issues are promptly answered with running `btrfs check --init-csum-tree` but my understanding is this will reset csum tree completely and I want to understand where exactly is the issue first.

Filesystem info:

```
[root@ls-fedora ArchiMedia]# btrfs filesystem usage .
Overall:
    Device size:          27.28TiB
    Device allocated:         12.02TiB
    Device unallocated:       15.27TiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:             11.84TiB
    Free (estimated):         15.44TiB  (min: 7.80TiB)
    Free (statfs, df):        15.44TiB
    Data ratio:               1.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:      512.00MiB  (used: 0.00B)
    Multiple profiles:              no

Data,single: Size:11.82TiB, Used:11.65TiB (98.57%)
   /dev/mapper/ArchiMedia     11.82TiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:102.00GiB, Used:100.80GiB (98.82%)
   /dev/mapper/ArchiMedia    102.00GiB
   /dev/mapper/AM-2  102.00GiB

System,RAID1: Size:32.00MiB, Used:1.30MiB (4.05%)
   /dev/mapper/ArchiMedia     32.00MiB
   /dev/mapper/AM-2   32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/mapper/ArchiMedia      4.45TiB
   /dev/mapper/AM-2   10.81TiB
```

Full `btrfs check` output:

```
[root@ls-fedora ~]# btrfs check -p /dev/mapper/ArchiMedia 
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/mapper/ArchiMedia
UUID: 6e222b94-0fa2-237d-284c-176e55472e30
[1/7] checking root items                      (0:06:50 elapsed, 17461366 items checked)
checksum verify failed on 369098752 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369115136 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369131520 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369147904 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962932944896 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962932961280 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962932977664 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962932994048 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962933010432 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x929dbce6274a6515cb28dcc6e1a5ee75bfdd7247c15ca701b2d272c358d1c544
checksum verify failed on 5964006686720 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006703104 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006719488 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006735872 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
[2/7] checking extents                         (0:17:42 elapsed, 6613880 items checked)
[3/7] checking free space cache                (0:06:57 elapsed, 12204 items checked)
checksum verify failed on 5962933010432 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x929dbce6274a6515cb28dcc6e1a5ee75bfdd7247c15ca701b2d272c358d1c544
checksum verify failed on 5962932994048 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962932944896 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962932961280 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962932977664 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006686720 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006703104 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006719488 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006735872 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369098752 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369115136 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369147904 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369131520 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
[4/7] checking fs roots                        (1:18:02 elapsed, 129168 items checked)
checksum verify failed on 5962933010432 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x929dbce6274a6515cb28dcc6e1a5ee75bfdd7247c15ca701b2d272c358d1c544
checksum verify failed on 5962932994048 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962932944896 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962932961280 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5962932977664 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006686720 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006703104 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006719488 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 5964006735872 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369098752 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369115136 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369147904 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
checksum verify failed on 369131520 wanted 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 found 0x6290e6592047ec80140a1252d31a8ba8a33a34cf578b5c8c4a081706b9416fa6
[5/7] checking csums (without verifying data)  (1:10:29 elapsed, 25512445 items checked)
[6/7] checking root refs                       (0:00:00 elapsed, 4 items checked)
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 12933797396480 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 100175282368
total tree bytes: 108361662464
total fs tree bytes: 2123726848
total extent tree bytes: 1481572352
btree space waste bytes: 3398233945
file data blocks allocated: 15714799702016
 referenced 13476542222336
```

dmesg lines corresponding to the addresses:

```
[ 6663.817055] BTRFS info (device dm-1): scrub: started on devid 1
[ 6663.818097] BTRFS info (device dm-1): scrub: started on devid 2
[ 6683.992056] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5962932944896 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 1498415104: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6683.992079] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5962932944896 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 1498415104: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6683.992092] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 22, gen 0
[ 6683.992254] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5962932961280 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 1498431488: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6683.992263] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5962932961280 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 1498431488: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6683.992270] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 23, gen 0
[ 6683.992477] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5962932977664 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 1498447872: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6683.992485] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5962932977664 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 1498447872: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6683.992492] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 24, gen 0
[ 6683.992647] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5962932994048 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 1498464256: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6683.992653] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5962932994048 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 1498464256: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6683.992663] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 25, gen 0
[ 6683.997006] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5962933010432 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 1498480640: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6683.997028] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5962933010432 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 1498480640: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6683.997041] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 26, gen 0
[ 6702.992865] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5964006686720 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 2572156928: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6702.992880] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5964006686720 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 2572156928: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6702.992888] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 27, gen 0
[ 6702.992985] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5964006703104 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 2572173312: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6702.992990] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5964006703104 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 2572173312: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6702.992994] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 28, gen 0
[ 6702.993083] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5964006719488 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 2572189696: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6702.993086] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5964006719488 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 2572189696: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6702.993090] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 29, gen 0
[ 6702.993177] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5964006735872 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 2572206080: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6702.993181] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 5964006735872 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 2572206080: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6702.993185] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 30, gen 0
[ 6721.512615] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 369098752 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 3645898752: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6721.512627] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 369098752 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 3645898752: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6721.512633] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 31, gen 0
[ 6721.512703] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 369115136 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 3645915136: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6721.512707] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 369115136 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 3645915136: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6721.512709] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 32, gen 0
[ 6721.512775] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 369131520 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 3645931520: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6721.512777] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 369131520 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 3645931520: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6721.512780] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 33, gen 0
[ 6721.516630] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 369147904 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 3645947904: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6721.516655] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 369147904 on dev /dev/mapper/AM-2, physical 3645947904: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[ 6721.516668] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/AM-2 errs: wr 29, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 34, gen 0
[ 6771.128355] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bad tree block start, want 5962933010432 have 0
[ 6771.157972] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962933010432 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926720)
[ 6771.157979] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962933014528 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926728)
[ 6771.159093] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962933018624 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926736)
[ 6771.159422] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962933022720 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926744)
[ 6913.335267] BTRFS warning (device dm-1): checksum error at logical 43113840640 on dev /dev/mapper/ArchiMedia, physical 44184436736, root 5, inode 4981, offset 131072, length 4096, links 1 (path: Archive/Develop/SDKs/Mobile/Android/android-sdk-windows/docs/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html)
[ 6913.335277] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/ArchiMedia errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 135, gen 0
[ 7229.380941] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bad tree block start, want 5962932994048 have 0
[ 7229.425140] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932994048 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926688)
[ 7229.425160] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932998144 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926696)
[ 7229.425170] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962933002240 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926704)
[ 7229.425176] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962933006336 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926712)
[ 7241.946885] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bad tree block start, want 5962932944896 have 0
[ 7241.982749] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932944896 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926592)
[ 7241.982775] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932948992 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926600)
[ 7241.982788] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932953088 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926608)
[ 7241.982797] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932957184 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926616)
[ 7314.107076] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bad tree block start, want 5962932961280 have 0
[ 7314.131362] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932961280 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926624)
[ 7314.131386] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932965376 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926632)
[ 7314.131396] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932969472 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926640)
[ 7314.131403] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932973568 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926648)
[ 7353.926345] BTRFS error (device dm-1): bad tree block start, want 5962932977664 have 0
[ 7353.964151] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932977664 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926656)
[ 7353.964169] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932981760 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926664)
[ 7353.964178] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932985856 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926672)
[ 7353.964185] BTRFS info (device dm-1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 5962932989952 (dev /dev/mapper/AM-2 sector 2926680)
```

Comment: Does the physical device have [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) capabilities?  If so, are there any warnings/errors or signs of degradation?

Comment: These are healthy brand new/slightly used drives with zero smart issues. The original issue stems from winbtrfs driver (multiple bsods leading to checksum block corruption)

Answer (score 5):

After reading lots of docs and search results, here's my findings:

1. `btrfs check` gives logical addresses in the errors
2. running `btrfs scrub` mentions tree 7, which is a checksum tree (`btrfs inspect-internal dump-tree -t 7 -r` to confirm)
3. you can get associated data offsets using `btrfs inspect-internal dump-tree -t 7 -b <logical_address> /dev/<dev>`
4. you can get associated filenames from data offsets using `btrfs inspect-internal logical-resolve <data_offset> /<mounted_fs_path>`

You can delete the files to remove corrupted entries in checksum tree.

You can also mount filesystem with `mount -t btrfs -o ro,rescue=ignoredatacsums /dev/<dev> /<mount_path>` and copying the affected files somewhere else (with the usual caveat that data may be corrupted).

Here's small pwsh script I wrote to get it semi-automatically:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/pwsh


$dev = "mapper/AM-2"
$mnt = "/mnt/ArchiMedia"
$csum_offsets = @(369098752, 369115136, 369131520, 369147904, 5962932944896, 5962932961280, 5962932977664, 5962932994048, 5962933010432, 5964006686720, 5964006703104, 5964006719488, 5964006735872)

$result = @()
foreach ($o in $csum_offsets)
{
    $output = (btrfs inspect-internal dump-tree -t 7 -b $o "/dev/$dev")
    $selected = ($output | Select-String -Pattern 'range start (\d+) end' -AllMatches)
    foreach ($m in $selected.Matches)
    {
        $data_offset = $m.Groups[1].Value
        $fname = (btrfs inspect-internal logical-resolve $data_offset $mnt)
        $result += $fname
    }
}
Write-Host "Affected files:"
$result | Get-Unique | Sort-Object
```